# How to say "she is like sunshine" in German?

Tags: english-to-german

Getting a surprise memorative tattoo for a special friend and just need to confirm it is correct. What is the correct way to say "she is like sunshine" in German?

Comment: What is your proposal, which should be confirmed?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say "Sie ist ein Sonnenschein" , if she has always a smile on her face,

or "Sie ist wie Sonnenschein", if she is important like the sunshine,

but if she is your girlfriend and "she is like sunshine **to me**" I'd say "Sie ist **mein** Sonnenschein" which has a different meaning.

Comment: "Sie ist wie Sonnenschein" is the correct translation but it is not as nice as your other two examples. I can not explain why in the moment. But before she/he gets the tattoo I wanted to point to this. ;-)

Comment: @Thomas: I would say `Sie ist wie ein Sonnenschein` - the added "ein" makes it as nice as the other, I would say.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Meister Schnitzel's answer.

Another less literal translation is:

"Sie strahlt wie die Sonne" = She's shining/smiling (double meaning in German) like the sun